# Rule in prolog to define whether an atom (which in this case a name) is the oldest son or not?

Tags: prolog

**Here's the code in prolog:**

```
son(blake, john).
son(blake, katey).
son(toney, john).
son(toney, katey).
son(flory, john).
son(flory, katey).
son(charlie, stark).
son(charlie, shrek).
son(valenti, stark).
son(valenti, shrek).

age(blake, 13).
age(toney, 15).
age(flory, 19).
age(charlie, 48).
age(valenti, 49).
```

**The definition of predicate and rules are:**

1. son(X, Y) means X is the son of Y
2. age(M, N) means age of M is N
3. siblings(P, Q) means P and Q are siblings

***My question is how to make a rule, let it be named oldestSon(X) that true if X is the oldestSon of a family?***

When the query is oldestSon(flory) and oldestSon(valenti) it returns true or yes, and when the query is oldest(toney) it returns false or no.

I give it a try by writing these lines of code:

```
oldestSon(X) :-
    son(X, _),
    son(Y, _),
    siblings(X, Y),
    age(X, ageX),
    age(Y, ageY),
    ageX >= ageY.
```

But, when I try to input a query, in any of the case, when the query is oldestSon(blake). It returns like this:

```
false ? ;
false ? ;
false ? ;
...
```

How to make it only make only one output **without using any external library** or **making another rule**?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because:

- it doesn't correctly describe the conditions for someone to be the oldest son in a family, and
- it uses constants (`ageX` and `ageY`) where it should be using variables (`AgeX` and `AgeY`).

Assuming that "*the oldest son in a family is the one who has no older sibling*", you can code:

```
oldestSon(X) :-
    age(X, AgeX),
    not( ( siblings(X, Y),
           age(Y, AgeY),
           AgeY > AgeX ) ).
```

I am also assuming that the predicate `siblings/2` is already defined as:

```
siblings(X, Y) :-
    son(X, Z),
    son(Y, Z),
    X \= Y.
```